# Accessing an IP subdomain on Android

Tags: android, dns, localhost, ip-address, host

Using Xampp on my Windows machine, I have subdomains for each websites which I'm developing. So for example, URL in the browser is:

- `https://Test-AAA.localhost/`
- `https://Test-BBB.localhost/`

I just started to wonder, if I can load that websites on my android (not rooted) devices to test?
When I will go to my IP address in the Android browser, I can see my server is loading.

Unfortunately I have no clue how to access subdomains. Obviously Loading `https://Test-AAA.111.1.11.111` is not working ...

I would be grateful for some tips :)

Comment: Is server loading perfectly without subdomain?

Comment: Yes, it is loading and showing proper result of "index.php".